# When to use "lui" and when to use "le" in the phrase "faire + infinitive"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, constructions-causatives

As I understand it, the phrase "faire + infinitive" is used to express "make someone do something". What has me puzzled, though, is why "lui" is used in one instance and "le" in the other.

> Tu **lui fais lire** ce pavé ?

{make him read this hefty book}

> M'aiderez-vous à trouver un moyen de **le faire redevenir** lui-même à nouveau ?

{make him become himself again}

Comment: Not relevevant to  **faire**, depends on **verb used in the infinitive**. Direct /indirect object choice. Lire (**à** quelqu'un) → indirect → lui. Redevenir (quelqu’un/quelque chose)  → direct → le. N

Comment: Note that both might be used in the first sentence: *tu le lui fais lire, ce pavé*.

Comment: @jlliagre Il se trouve que c’est l’une des questions que j’ai posées à mes débuts. Cette construction qui me vient machinalement à l'esprit à présent, ça, je m’en serais gratté la tête de frustration à l’époque. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prescriptive rule is that, when a declarative sentence is made into a causative one, its erstwhile subject is demoted to the next free slot in the argument structure (Subject > Direct Object > Indirect Object (*à*) > Oblique Object (*par*/*de*). In some cases, the ex-subject can drop to a lower spot than the first free one.

With less lingo and more examples:

**For a transitive verb:**

> **Le bébé** s'est endormi (The baby fell asleep)
>
> **Il** s'est endormi
>
> La berceuse a fait s'endormir **le bébé** (the nursery song made the baby fall asleep)
>
> Elle **l**'a fait s'endormir

In the causative constructive, it's *berceuse* that fills the subject slot, which displaces *bébé*, making it drop to the direct object slot.

**For an intransitive verb:**

> **Les élèves** ont lu l'article (The pupils read the article)
>
> **Ils** l'ont lu
>
> La prof a fait lire l'article **aux élèves**
>
> Elle **leur** a fait lire l'article (1)

As both the subject and direct object slots are filled (by *la prof* and *l'article*, respectively), *les élèves* drops to the indirect object slot.

It's also possible to mark *les élèves* with *par* instead:

> La prof a fait lire l'article **par les élèves**

But this is not very common.

**For an intransitive verb used without an object**:

Two constructions are possible:

> **Les élèves** lisent (the pupils read)
>
> **Ils** lisent
>
> La prof fait lire **les élèves** (Elle **les** fait lire)
>
> La prof fait lire **aux élèves** (Elle **leur** fait lire)

Transitive verbs used intransitively can either follow the intransitive construction (the demoted subject ends up as a direct object) or the transitive construction (the demoted subject ends up as an indirect object)

**With three arguments verbs**:

> **Le garçon** sert aux clients leurs verres (The barman serves their drinks to the clients)
>
> **Il** les leur sert
>
> Le patron fait servir leurs verres aux clients **par le garçon** (The bar-owner makes the barman serve their drinks to the clients)
>
> Le patron fait servir leurs verres aux clients **par lui**

As all three central argument positions are filled, the logical subject of *servir* ends up marked as an oblique agent.

---

The rule, once understood, is actually quite simple, but exceptions like what happens with transitive verbs without an object or the *à*/*par* alternation can make the input quite confusing for a learner.

Furthermore, the actual usage of French speakers can diverge from these rules. Because the direct object is a grammatical role mostly used for inanimates affected by the action of the verb, it can be an awkward role to assign to an agentive human being (and the demoted subject of a causative construction is almost always highly agentive), so you'll hear sentences like those bellow with some regularity:

> Je **lui** ai fait dormir (I made him sleep)
>
> Je **lui** ai fait se dépécher (I made him hurry up)

Because the indirect object is a much more usual grammatical role for humans, it's preferred to that of direct object.

Some speakers might also not follow the demotion chain to the end, and leave the demoted subject in an already filled spot. This is mostly restricted to cases when it's a pronoun and cooccur with a full noun phrase:

> Elle **les** a fait lire **l'article** (where *les* is *les élèves*)
>
> Le patron **lui** fait servir leurs verres **aux clients** (where *lui* is *au garçon*)

If you want to use a causative construction as a learner, just stick to the prescriptive rules and ignore even the prescriptively licit exceptions, at least at first, because this is the simplest way to form the construction.

---

(1) There are two options to pronominalize *l'article*: Elle **le** leur a fait lire and Elle leur a fait **le** lire

Answer (score 0):

> Tu **lui** fais lire ce pavé. -> Tu fais lire ce pavé **à XXX**.
>
> M'aiderez-vous à trouver un moyen de **le** faire redevenir lui-même à nouveau ? -> M'aiderez-vous à trouver un moyen de faire redevenir **XXX** lui-même à nouveau ?

Ce qui change est que dans le 1er cas "lui" remplace un COI (complément d'objet indirect, qu'on remarque car il commence par la préposition "à"), alors que dans le second on remplace un COD (complément d'objet direct, qu'on remarque à son absence de préposition)

Notez que ceci provient de mon expérience personnelle, et je ne suis pas certain que cette règle soit valide dans tous les cas.

Comment: Bien sûr que c'est une règle. **Le** est complément d'objet direct et **lui** est complément d'objet indirect. [Pronoms personnels](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/10/grammaire/166.html). Ce que l'OP n'avait pas vu c'est que **faire** n'a rien à voir avec le choix du pronom personnel qui dépend du verbe qui l'introduit.